# Visual Studio 2017 not showing compilation exceptions at first run

Tags: .net, exception, visual-studio-2017, xna, monogame

I'm working on a MonoGame project, and VisualStudio only shows the exception errors at second build. At the first build the game window just closes, and nothing happens. I've checked every errors / project output.

If it can help :

- **MonoGame** is *v3.6*
- **Visual Studio** is *v15.7.3*
- **.NET Framework** is *v4.7*

It apparently only occurs when I'm using MonoGame, everything is fine with other C# / C++ projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the bin folder in the project which will force all the code to get recompiled.  this normally works.
VS will recreate the bin folder when it doesn't exist.

Comment: Ok that worked, but for how long ? will I have to do it again at some point ?